# Comparing Only First 4 columns from File1 (CSV Formatted ) to First 4 columns in File2 and printing all columns from File1 i

Tags: awk

I'm Trying to compare two Files in CSV format

First File is dynamic , daily the columns will be added ,
on second File it has only 4 columns ( static )
comparing First 4 columns on File1 to 4 columns on File2 and printing all columns from File1 which matches from File2

Ex :

File1

```
AIXTSM1,VHOST,10.199.114.72,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ADMET007,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ADMET014,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM1,VHOST,AGGREGATE,DAILY_2200_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD5,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM1,PHOST,APLEE01,DAILY_2000_SU_W3,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM1,PHOST,APYRK02,DAILY_2000_SU_W3,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,PHOST,APYRK04,DAILY_1800_V7K,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ARCLIC01,DAILY_2200_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD5,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,PHOST,ARIELN,DAILY_1800_V7K,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ASMET005,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,PHOST,ASMET014,WIN_INCRE_2000,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ASMET038,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD2,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ASMET042,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ASMET044,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ASMET046,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ASMET068,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ASMET069,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ASMET070,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ASMET071,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ASMET072,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ASMET073,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM1,PHOST,ASMET074,DAILY_INCR_1900,COMP,COMP,COMP
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ASMET084-T,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3,COMP,COMP,COMP
```

File2

```
AIXTSM1,VHOST,10.199.114.72,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ADMET007,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ADMET014,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD
AIXTSM1,VHOST,AGGREGATE,DAILY_2200_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD5
```

Result

```
AIXTSM1,VHOST,10.199.114.72,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3,COMP,COMP,COMP,OK
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ADMET007,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3,COMP,COMP,COMP,OK
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ADMET014,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,COMP,COMP,COMP,OK
AIXTSM1,VHOST,AGGREGATE,DAILY_2200_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD5,COMP,COMP,COMP,OK
```

Code

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ arr[$2]=$1 $2 $3 $4; next } { print $0, (arr[$2]==$1 $2 $3 $4?"OK":"NOK") }' OFS=, File2 File1
```

But it matches only first line .

Comment: your file2, first line is missing "3" at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your expected output's first line is typo? Since all 4 fields of Input_file2 are NOT coming in Input_file1. Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==NR{a[$1,$2,$3,$4];next} (($1,$2,$3,$4) in a){print $0, "OK"}' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too here.

```
awk -F, '                ##Mentioning field separator as comma(,) here for all lines of Input_file(s).
BEGIN{                   ##Starting BEGIN section of awk program here.
  FS=OFS=","             ##Setting field separator and output field separator as comma(,) here.
}
FNR==NR{                 ##FNR==NR condition will be when 1st Input_file named Input_file2 is being read.
  a[$1,$2,$3,$4]         ##Creating an array named a whose index is $1,$2,$3,$4 fields of Input_file2 lines.
  next                   ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                        ##Closing first condition block now.
(($1,$2,$3,$4) in a){    ##Checking condition if $1,$2,$3,$4 of Input_file1 are present in array a if yes then do following.
  print $0,"OK"          ##Printing current line with OFS and OK string here now.
}
' Input_file2  Input_file1   ##Mentioning Input_file name(s) Input_file2 and Input_file1 here.
```

Comment: Thanks , your explanation help in understanding better

Comment: @XYZ, glad that it helped you, keep posting and keep learning on great site SO.